# Config Action Cable for Heroku - Error localhost:3000/cable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have problem with my app with Action Cable on Heroku:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/cable' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My production.rb:

```
  config.action_cable.url = "wss://NAME.herokuapp.com/cable"   
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://NAME.herokuapp.com', 'http://NAME.herokuapp.com']
```

I tried to specify the server in the cable.js as well:

```
@App ||= {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("wss://NAME.herokuapp.com/cable")
```

I tried to change it in development.rb just in case but nothing helps. The Heroku is still trying to connect to localhost.

Another weird thing that has nothing in common with it I think, is that the app is not able to process some js code like: alert('test') or console.log("haha") despite of some js code works and I tried assets:precompile as well.

In localhost, everything works perfectly. Any idea what can be wrong with heroku and the setting?

Answer (score 0):

While ActionCable was in development, I remember you had to startup 2 servers for the cable connection and for Rails. I don't think that is still needed for the final release.

My guess is that you don't have Redis provisioned on your Heroku instance, whereas in Production, ActionCable relies on Redis for it's server communication.

To fix this, you should do the following:

`heroku addons:add redistogo`

`heroku config | grep REDISTOGO_URL`

In your `config/cable.yml`, set the Redis url to the one given. I guess you should also be able to use `ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']` in place of the url.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I set up the redis server and this shouldn't be the issue but thanks anyway. I think this is about to tell heroku how to connect to the right server in websocket.

Answer (score -1):

If it's working locally but not remotely it may be an SSL problem.  Make sure you properly set up an SSL endpoint for the secure websocket (wss):
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Also, there is an excellent blog post on Heroku about how to set up Action Cable: https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable.  Alas, the article does not mention the necessity of setting up an SSL endpoint for the Heroku deployment to work.